# Why looping an Add operations in LinkedList takes longer than ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, performance-testing

So I know that `LinkedList` should be much faster (compared to `ArrayList`) when the main operation is `add` as it doesn't need to copy the array that runs out of empty slots.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322742/5458827) :

> Another benefit of using a LinkedList arise when you add or remove from the head of the list, since those operations are O(1), while they are O(n) for ArrayList.

So I created this small program to benchmark it. To my surprise, it turned the other way around, so the `ArrayList` is faster. Which seems counterintuitive.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1000; i < 100000000; i *=5) {
        System.out.println(" - - - - ");
        System.out.println("size " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(i));
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        populateList(list, i);
        list = null;

        List<Integer>list2 = new LinkedList<>();
        populateList(list2, i);
    }

}

private static void populateList(List<Integer> list, long size) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(list.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " Diff: " + (after - start));
}
```

And the output is:

---

size 1,000

java.util.ArrayList Diff: 0

java.util.LinkedList Diff: 0

---

size 5,000

java.util.ArrayList Diff: 1

java.util.LinkedList Diff: 0

---

size 25,000

java.util.ArrayList Diff: 3

java.util.LinkedList Diff: 2

---

size 125,000

java.util.ArrayList Diff: 5

java.util.LinkedList Diff: 4

---

size 625,000

java.util.ArrayList Diff: 20

java.util.LinkedList Diff: 13

---

size 3,125,000

java.util.ArrayList Diff: 104

java.util.LinkedList Diff: 1254

---

size 15,625,000

java.util.ArrayList Diff: 3274

java.util.LinkedList Diff: 4490

---

size 78,125,000

java.util.ArrayList Diff: 14457

java.util.LinkedList Diff: 88370

Comment: You are not adding to the head of the linked list as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting to the end of list for which both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` are `O(1)` as the LinkedList implementation is a doubly-linked list which has a tail pointer as well.

To insert at the head, pass the index as well.

```
list.add(0, i);
```

Also see: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)